# How to change an Xbox controller's assignment in .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-10, xbox, xinput

In Windows 10 UWP, how can an app developer change which controller number a gamepad is assigned to, purely in code?

For a reference scenario, in the Xbox 360 versions of the Rock Band games, it is possible to have controllers assigned to a specific logged-in Gamertag. (Also Rock Band 4 for Xbox One, but with controller numbers hidden externally, it loses relevance for the scenario.) When this is done, the controller number is changed to the one the player was already logged into.
For example, given for Rock Band 3:

- Player 1, Gamertag BJohn, Guitar (Stratocaster)
- Player 2, Gamertag BPaul, Keyboard
- Player 3, Gamertag BGeorge, Pro Guitar (Squier Strat)
- Player 4, Gamertag BPete, Drums

If BGeorge wanted to play drums for the next song, and BPete was fine with being on the Squier, BGeorge could press Start on the Drum controller and select "Switch to BGeorge", swapping the controller assignments and resulting in:

- Player 1, Gamertag BJohn, Guitar (Stratocaster)
- Player 2, Gamertag BPaul, Keyboard
- Player 3, Gamertag BGeorge, Drums
- Player 4, Gamertag BPete, Pro Guitar (Squier Strat)

I already know that it can be done in Windows due to a different game (I can't remember which one, but I think it was for Windows Desktop) suddenly changing my controller number on me on a Mad Catz fightpad. Problem is, I don't know if it's something that can be done using MonoGame or the Windows.Gaming.Input namespace, and I'd like to stick with C# for the time being.